# asp.net mvc. Passing a list via viewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, viewdata

Hi does anyone know how to pass a list throught the "ViewData".  This is what I'm trying but I think I'm missing a cast some where.

```
List<GalleryModel> galleryList = new List<GalleryModel>();
        galleryList.Add(new GalleryModel() { isApproved = true, uri = "www.cnn1.com" });
        galleryList.Add(new GalleryModel() { isApproved = true, uri = "www.cnn2.com" });

        ViewData["SomeList"] = galleryList;
```

here's my aspx page code:

```
 <% List<myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models.GalleryModel> galList = ViewData["SomeList"];  %>
<% foreach (var gal in galList) { %>
<%= gal.uri%>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this line:

```
List<myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models.GalleryModel> galList = ViewData["SomeList"];
```

change it to

```
var galList = ViewData["SomeList"] as List<myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models.GalleryModel>;
```

Comment: Worked Great.  Thanks!  I don't know why the other type of casting doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it in the view:

```
<% var galList = ViewData["SomeList"] as List<myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models.GalleryModel>;  %>
```

or

```
<% var galList = (List<myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models.GalleryModel>) ViewData["SomeList"];  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast the object out of the ViewData collection as the type you need to interact with:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myNS.CM.AVDTalentApplication.Models" %>

<% foreach(var gal in (List<GalleryModel>) ViewData["SomeList"]) %>
<% { %>
    <%= gal.uri %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: it didn't like that type of casting.  see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though all the above answers are correct, I would strongly suggest making use of [view models](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/aspnet-mvc-using-custom-viewmodels-with-post-action-methods/).

Comment: oh shoot, this was meant as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this code to controller:

ViewData("SomeRole") = "hidden"/"visible"

To your html <li style="visibility:
@ViewBag.SomeRole'>@Html.ActionLink("Tenant", "Index", "{controller}", New With {.area = ""}, Nothing)